# how to do add row span in latex

Tags: tables

Hi i am trying to plot the table like given in image .. can anyone help
I tried this code
its not exactly working like this

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{multirow,tabularx}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}
\begin{document}\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|*{5}{Y|}}
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{State of Health} 
  &\multicolumn{3}{c|}{Fasting Value}&After Eating\\
\cline{2-4} 
             &Minimum       &Maximum &low &2 hours after eating\\
\hline
Healthy      &70            &100     &a &Less than 140\\
\hline
Pre-Diabetes &101           &126     &a &140 to 200\\
\hline
Diabetes     &More than 126 &N/A     &a &More than 200\\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: all  of your previous questions have also been answered -- however no answer has been accepted by you -- in case the answers provided meet your requirement, it is customary to accept the answer in appreciation of the fact that someone has spent time and effort to find a solution to your problem area

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{multirow,tabularx,booktabs}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\arraybackslash}X}
% \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{tabularx}{0.6\textwidth}{*{5}{Y}}
\toprule
State of Health 
  &\multicolumn{3}{c}{Fasting Value}
   &\multicolumn{1}{c}{After Eating}\\
\cmidrule(r){2-4} \cmidrule(l){5-5}
             &Min     &Max &Low &2 hours\\
\midrule
Healthy      &70            &100     &a &$<$ 140\\
\midrule
Pre-Diabetes &101           &126     &a &140 -- 200\\
\midrule
Diabetes     &$>$126 &N/A     &a &$>$ 200\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

**OR**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{multirow,tabularx,booktabs}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\arraybackslash}X}
% \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{tabularx}{0.6\textwidth}{p{3cm}*{3}{Y}p{3cm}}
\toprule
State of Health 
  &\multicolumn{3}{c}{Fasting Value}
   &\multicolumn{1}{c}{After Eating}\\
\cmidrule(r){2-4} \cmidrule(l){5-5}
             &\multicolumn{1}{c}{Min}     &\multicolumn{1}{c}{Max} &\multicolumn{1}{c}{Low} &\multicolumn{1}{c}{2 hours}\\
\midrule
Healthy      &70            &100     &a &$<$ 140\\
\midrule
Pre-Diabetes &101           &126     &a &140 -- 200\\
\midrule
Diabetes     &$>$126 &N/A     &a &$>$ 200\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit with respect to comments**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{multirow,tabularx,booktabs}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\arraybackslash}X}
% \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{p{3cm}*{6}{Y}}
\toprule
State of Health 
  &\multicolumn{3}{c}{Fasting Value}
   &\multicolumn{3}{c}{After Eating}\\
\cmidrule(r){2-4} \cmidrule(l){5-7}
             &{Min}     
               &{Max} 
                  &{Low} 
                     &2hrs
                        &3hrs
                           &4hrs\\
\midrule
Healthy      
   &70            
      &100     
         &a 
            &$<$ 140
               &
                  &\\
\midrule
Pre-Diabetes 
   &101           
      &126     
         &a 
            &140 -- 200
               &
                  &\\
\midrule
Diabetes     
   &$>$126 
      &N/A     
         &a 
            &$>$ 200
               &
                  &\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: how to add 3 clumn under after eating thats issue. the table you are printing the given code is already doing this

Comment: request a hand sketch of the desired output

Comment: already pasted a desired format table image in the question you can see

Comment: please see the edit above

Comment: thanks what if i want to show table lines too

Comment: if you are referring to vertical lines these are not generally desirable giving a jailed look to the contents --

Comment: and how to increase the width of columns if the txt is large

Comment: it would be appreciable if a fresh requirement is placed in a new question to attract a larger audience

Answer (score 4):

Your question is not entirely clear. Provided MWE (Minimal Working Example) doesn't reproduce showed image. So,

- how many columns table should have
- is is two horizontal lines between row "1" and "2" desired or it should be before row"1"?
- are symbols at the left side of table part of table?

**Edit:** Considered OP comments.

Anyway, you may liked the following table design, which employ new `tabularray` package, consider seven columns and three rows in table body:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe,
            margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
    
\noindent\begin{tblr}{%
            hline{1,3,Z}=1pt, hline{2}={solid}, hline{4-Y} ={dashed}, vlines,
            colspec = {l *{6}{X[1,l]}},
            rowsep = 3pt
             }
\SetCell[r=2]{l} State of Health
    & \SetCell[c=3]{c} Fasting Value
        &   &   & \SetCell[c=3]{c} After Eating
                    &   &                       \\ 
    & Minimum   & Maximum   & Low
    & Minimum   & Maximum   & Low   \\
Healthy         & a & a & a     & a & a & a     \\
Pre-Diabetes    & a & a & a     & a & a & a     \\
Diabetes        & a & a & a     & a & a & a     \\
    \end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

[image]

or classical "professional" looks using `booktabs`, `makecell`, `multirow` and `tabularx` packages :-)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{booktabs, multirow, makecell, tabularx}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight}X}
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand\mcc{O{1}m}{\multicolumn{#1}{c}{#2}}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
{\setcellgapes{2pt}
 \makegapedcells
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ l LLl LLl }
    \toprule
\multirow{2.4}{*}{\makecell[l]{State of\\ Health}}
    & \mcc[3]{Fasting Value}    
    & \mcc[3]{After Eating}         \\ 
    \cmidrule(r){2-4}\cmidrule(l){5-7}
    & Minimum   & Maximum   & Low
    & Minimum   & Maximum   & Low   \\
    \midrule
Healthy         & a & a & a     & a & a & a     \\
Pre-Diabetes    & a & a & a     & a & a & a     \\
Diabetes        & a & a & a     & a & a & a     \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, no actually its not  horizontal lines between row "1" and "2" . i tried this cdoe but it gives error .. i need to include any package or file?

Comment: @Alex, all what is  needed, is included in the MWE. What is error? Where you compile? By Overleaf? It may be a case the it has not installed `tabullarray` package.

Comment: yeah i am using overleaf

Comment: error file tabularray.sty not found

Comment: @Alex, than you need to ad it to your folder. Overleaf not contain it yet. How to do this, ask their support.